# Deploy Office.Interop.Word Word 2010 on Server 2008 and calling methods from ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, ms-word, windows-server-2008, office-interop

I want to deploy Microsoft Word 2010 and Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word on Microsoft Windows Server 2008.

The user (just a few) visits an .ASPX page. Data is input there or selected from the database from the aspx page. Once data is collected, I want to invoke the a Word application instance on the SERVER and progematically insert the data into ranges in the Word document. That doc gets saved in a folder on the server and/or downloaded onto the user's local machine.

Can I deploy Microsoft Word and the interop assemblies on Win 2008 Server? If not, is there another solution?

Comment: Using office interop on server is not supported. Look here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757 You can build your document with xml or use a 3rd party library that doesn't require interop.

Comment: You have to install office PIA on server http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3508

Answer (score 3):

i was facing the same error, after spending 2 days of my life i found this solution.

You need to assign permissions to the Microsoft office 2003 - 2007 object.

Please have a look.

**Step 1**

Go to the Component Services > Computers > My Computer > and select DCom Config
after this, go to the right pane and find "Microsoft Word 98 - 2003 Document" object

[image]

**Step 2**

Right click on the component and go to the properties and select "Security Tab"

[image]

**Step 3**

Add NETWORK, NETWORKSERVICE, IIS_IUSRS and Administrator users and assign them "Local" and "Remote" Access Permissions
[image]

**Step 4**

Now go to the "Identity tab" and select "This User"
In user and password textboxes type administrator crediantals and press "Apply" and "OK (must to save the changes)"

[image]

**Step 5**

Now restart your machine.
it'll works.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Don't use Office on Server. Use Open XML...

[See this Link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757):

> Microsoft strongly recommends that developers find alternatives to
>   Automation of Office if they need to develop server-side solutions.
>   Because of the limitations to Office's design, changes to Office
>   configuration are not enough to resolve all issues. Microsoft strongly
>   recommends a number of alternatives that do not require Office to be
>   installed server-side, and that can perform most common tasks more
>   efficiently and more quickly than Automation. Before you involve
>   Office as a server-side component in your project, consider
>   alternatives.
>
> Most server-side Automation tasks involve document creation or
>   editing. Office 2007 supports new Open XML file formats that let
>   developers create, edit, read, and transform file content on the
>   server side. These file formats use the System.IO.Package.IO namespace
>   in the Microsoft .NET 3.x Framework to edit Office files without using
>   the Office client applications themselves. This is the recommended and
>   supported method for handling changes to Office files from a service.
>
> The Open XML file formats are a public standard. To obtain a copy of
>   the specification, visit the following Web site:

[ECMA-376 Open XML Standard](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-376.htm)